# Can someone please explain to me why the set {1, 1/2, 1, 1/3, 1, 1/4, ...} has two points of accumulation?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A point of accumulation in $X$ is a point $c$ where every neighborhood of $c$ contains at least one point of $X$ distinct from $c$

For example, the neighborhood of $1$ is $\{1, 1/2\}, \{1,1/2,1\}, \{1, 1/2, 1, 1/3\}...$, since it contains itself, therefore $1$ is definitely not a point of accumulation

But the solution states that the two points are accumulation are $1$ and $0$, and neither of them belongs to the set.

I am very confused, can someone help?

Comment: How is your set different from $\{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots\}$?  Are you talking about limit points of a sequence?

Comment: As stated, the only limit point is $0$. (Limit points need not belong to the set.) However, if it was a _sequence_ $(1, 1/2, 1, 1/3, 1, 1/4, ...)$, then 1 and 0 would be limit points, I believe. (Note the $()$ signs instead of $\{\}$ signs — $()$ means sequence, $\{\}$ means set.)

Comment: What @Batominovski said. It is about accumulation points of a sequence, I bet.

Comment: Like Batominovsky and Daniel, I suspect that the question is actually about the sequence $$\left\langle 1,\frac12,1,\frac13,1,\frac14,1,\ldots\right\rangle\;.$$ You may find the discussion in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/577287/12042) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not **the** neighborhoods of $1$, moreover, they're not even neighborhoods since those doesn't contain any open set (a *neighborhood* is either an open set or a set which contains an open set).

$1$ is not an accumulation point of that set since, for example, the neighborhood $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right)$ doesn't contain any point from the set besides $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The point $0$ is only limit point of your set. there is no other limit point.