# Cluster Point || Limit Point || Accumulation Point

Tags: general-topology

I am a very beginner of introductory course in analysis.

It looks that these three words - Cluster Point || Limit Point || Accumulation Point - are interchangeably used.

Is there any difference(like contextual or whatever mathematcially important difference).

And also one more question:

Cluster point of a set || Cluster point of s sequence.

Is there any difference between two cluster points? I mean, I've seen the latter one, but what I know is that cluster point is a notion for set not a sequence.(of course sequence is a indexed set, but it's more specific anyway to use the word cluster point)

Comment: I think the conceptual difference between *limit point* and *accumulation point* is that for a limit point one has a specific sequence in mind for which this is the limit. For accumulation point one knows that there is *some* sequence with this limit, but none is emphasized.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/577287/75923).

Comment: This is one of those cases where usage can vary from book to book and from paper to paper, and also over time (usage from 40+ year old books might differ from current books), such as is the case with "natural number" regarding whether $0$ is to be included. Thus, you'll need to keep track of how each particular author uses the words, unless your reading is restricted to just a few sources that agree.